# C# encryption method doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography

This is a method, for encrypting a text and returning the cipher text:

```
public static string Encrypt(this string clearText, CryptologyMethod method)
{
    ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = null;
    switch (method)
    {
        case CryptologyMethod.TripleDes:
            cryptoTransform = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(Config.TripleDesKey, Config.TripleDesIV);
            break;
        case CryptologyMethod.AES:
            cryptoTransform = new AesCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(Config.AesKey, Config.AesIV);
            break;
    }
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(clearText);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return memoryStream.Text();
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum CryptologyMethod
{
    TripleDes,
    AES
}
```

`Text()` is an extension method, to read the content of a stream:

```
public static string Text(this Stream stream)
{
    return new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Also, `Config.TripleDesKey` and other properties return array of bytes read from configuration file.

**The problem is that when I use this extension method, the result is always an empty string:**

string cipherText = "some clear text".Encrypt(CryptologyMethod.TripleDes);
// cipherText is empty

Comment: I didn't downvote - but: what is the problem exactly ? compiler error ? "wrong" encryption ?

Comment: For someone with almost 5k rep, you have no clue how to ask a question. What is the error, what is the input, what is the expected output? Do you realize you need to reset you stream position after filling it?

Comment: Everyone, I'm so sorry, I updated the question. Thanks from reopening this question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've had that issue before, the solution was pretty obvious once I figured it out and completely opaque before then.

The problem was that ReadToEnd is relative, as in "from current location to end".  The problem being that "current position" already WAS "end" because I'd just finished writing to the end of the stream.  So I would fix your problem like this:

```
public static string Text(this Stream stream)
{
    stream.Position = 0
    return new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Worked for me with a similar issue, hope it helps.

Comment: Why it produces some `?` marks in diamonds? Also when I want to decrypt it with the same key, it says *Length of the data to decrypt is invalid*.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different problem.  Does that mean that you've got your stream handling fixed now?